# JavaScript error: “is not a function”

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a problem with js on change condition. This is my code:

```
self.onAbsenTypeChange = function(prodTarget, prodActual,absentCode) {
    if ( self.saveType() === 'target' || self.saveType() === 'actual' )
    {
        if (jQuery.isFunction(absentCode))
        {
            if (absentCode() == 'A')
            {
                prodTarget(parseToFloat(prodTarget()));
                prodActual(parseToFloat(prodActual()));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (absentCode == 'A')
            {
                prodTarget(parseToFloat(prodTarget));
                prodActual(parseToFloat(prodActual));
            }
        }
    }
};
```

When I look in Firebug, the code has an error:

> "is not a function"

Like this:

[image: error]

```html
<select class="show-tick form-control absent-type" id="ddlAbsentType"
                                    data-live-search="true"
                                    data-bind="value: $data.AbsentTypeComputed, options: $root.AbsentSelectList,
                                        optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue : 'Value', optionsCaption:'', isSelectPicker:{}, event : {change : $root.onAbsenTypeChange($data.ProdTarget, $data.ProdActual, $data.AbsentCodeEblek)}"></select>
```

Above is the code for calling my js function.

Comment: `absentCode()` ? Why parenthesis(`()`) ?

Comment: If `prodTarget` isn't a function, then it has to be something else. We can't tell what because you haven't shown us where it comes from. It is the first argument to the function, but you haven't shared how the function is called.

Comment: Please post the part of code that calls that function

Comment: @Matt-SL — Why would it be expecting `this.prodTarget` when `prodTarget` is an argument to the function?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

prodTarget is not a function but an argument of the function. Try this:

```
prodTarget = parseToFloat(prodTarget);
```